# Why my Eloquent all() return trash also?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, eloquent

Hello I have code like this http://pastie.org/10852864 why when I call routes, I got result with trash http://prnt.sc/b8jxhh.

But when I change to this http://pastie.org/10852865, It work's as expected without trash.

But the second one I need to write config(...) everywhere.

Comment: What do you mean trash?

Comment: Does your config/database.php file use that database connection as the default?

Comment: @geckob the first link returns Product::withTrashed()->get(); #Brett no, I have 2 connections.

Comment: @geckob the first link Product::all(), return http://prnt.sc/b8jxhh look at deleted_at, this not work as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you don't run parent constructor so no special trait methods won't be applied - in this case `bootSoftDeletes` method won't be run.

All you need is to run parent constructor. instead of:

```
public function __construct()
{
    config(['database.connections.pos.database' => 'mydata']);
}
```

You should use:

```
public function __construct()
{
    config(['database.connections.pos.database' => 'mydata']);
    parent::__construct();
}
```

Comment: Thx buddy, I have bad knowledge about oop ^_^

Comment: Branch::create(['name' => 'SuperMall']), then I check my db any new record, but null name, why?

Comment: @HataBomba If you have new question, ask one

Comment: ok sir, anyways this is happen when I create model from "pos" connection only, when MyModel use default connection will works well, so I think this is still relevant, ok I will create new one if U think needed?

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain what this line does:

```
config(['database.connections.pos.database' => 'mydata']);
```

It will actually go to `config/database.php` and look for `connections` array and set the `pos.database` to be `mydata`

The array looks like this:

```
'connections' => [

    'sqlite' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlite',
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
        'prefix' => '',
    ],

    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => false,
        'engine' => null,
    ],

    'pgsql' => [
        'driver' => 'pgsql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'prefix' => '',
        'schema' => 'public',
    ],

],
```

As you can see, most of the values are taken from the `.env` file. You can set this in your `.env` and you don't have to set it using the lines you put.

The example I had, in this case, assuming I am using `MySQL` and the username and password as follows:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=freshbook
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

**EDITED**

So, if you need to have two connections, you can actually create two controllers for two different database.

```
class MysqlController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct() {
      config(['database.connections.mysql.database' => 'mydata']);
      parent::__construct();


    }

    public function getSomething() {

    }
}
```

In routes.php

```
Router::get('/get', function() {

   $user = App\User::find(1);

   if ($user-id == 1) {
      $ctrl = new App\Http\Controllers\MysqlController();

      return $ctrl->getSomething(); 

}
```

Hope you get the idea

Comment: yes but I hv 2 connections mysql and pos, and every customer have difference DB_DATABASE, so I change DB_DATABASE using config(...)

Comment: your code will not change DB_DATABASE to mydata, is still default forge

Comment: @HataBomba Did you map your route to any controller method after change the db in construct?

Comment: As @marcin stated, I forgot to include the parent construct